# How to broadcast a embed to different servers discord python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, chatbot

So im trying to have a embed broadcast to servers it in. I was already able to have it broadcast messages but for some reason it doesnt let me do embeds. And its not giving me a error either. It just wont send the embed to the other servers. But it will send the embed to the server i made the embed in. Any help would be awesome thanks!

```
@client.command()
async def make_embed(ctx):
    def check(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel

    await ctx.send('Please insert a title')
    title = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
  
    await ctx.send('Please insert a description')
    desc = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
  
    await ctx.send("Would you like to broadcast this message?")
    broadcast = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
  
    b = discord.Embed(title=title.content, description=desc.content, broadcast=broadcast.content, color=0xfffff)
    if broadcast == "yes":
       for server in client.guilds:
        for channel in server.text_channels:
          await channel.send(embed=b)
    else:
      embed = discord.Embed(title=title.content, description=desc.content, broadcast=broadcast.content, color=0xfffff)
      await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't getting any errors, because you are silently ignoring all exceptions with `except Exception: continue`. The error happens in `await channel.send(b)` The default parameter for `.send()` always a `str`, not a `discord.Embed`. Use `.send(embed=b)` instead.

There could also be a problem with the `else` block. It runs when `try` doesn't encounter any exceptions. In this case it would break the loop after successfully sending a single message to a server.

Comment: I see so how would I specify that im sending a embed? @Daste

Comment: The same was as you did at the end of your code - `await ctx.send(embed=b)`.

Comment: I edited my answer to be more clear about the possible solutions. You are saying that you get no errors, so the exception handling is my first guess. Try entirely removing the `try/except/else` block and see if things start working.

Comment: I deleted all of that and yet its still not working and it doesnt give me any errors either. @Daste

Comment: Does it send any of the messages defined in your command? Please check how far the code reaches before breaking. Also, please update the code in your question, so I can see what changed exactly.

Comment: Yes so it sends the embed with the description and the title but it just wont broadcast the  embed. It can broadcast normal text messages but thats about it @Daste. And I updated my code on my orginal question